# How to keep div hide after page refresh when div id removed at time reaches <0?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

What i am doing here is I am removing div once time becomes than zero, It is working but when i am refreshing the page that div is displayed again on the page which i don't need.

How can i do this ?

Here is my code

```
var cdtd = function(id,end) {
var start = new Date();
var timeDiff = end.getTime() - start.getTime();

if(timeDiff <=0 ) 
{
  $('#bidbar1').remove();
 // alert('We have lift off!'); 

    return;
 }

  var seconds = Math.floor(timeDiff / 1000);
  var minutes = Math.floor(seconds / 60);
 var hours = Math.floor(minutes / 60);
 var days = Math.floor(hours / 24);
 hours %= 24;
  minutes %= 60;
 seconds %= 60;
 $( id + " .days").html(days);
 $( id + " .hours").html(hours);
 $( id + " .minutes").html( minutes);
 $( id + " .seconds").html( seconds );
 console.log(id + " .hoursBox",$( id + "       .hoursBox").length,id,end,hours,minutes,seconds)
  var timer = setTimeout(function(){cdtd(id,end)},1000);

  }
  cdtd("#counter1",new Date("march 15, 2014  12:30:00"));
  cdtd("#counter2",new Date("march 15, 2014 12:31:00"));
   cdtd("#counter3",new Date("march 15, 2014 10:33:00"));
  cdtd("#counter4",new Date("march 14, 2014 10:35:00"));
   cdtd("#counter5",new Date("june 2, 2014 10:55:00"));
  cdtd("#counter6",new Date("April 2, 2014 10:30:00"));
 cdtd("#counter7",new Date("April 3, 2014 00:01:00"));
 cdtd("#counter8",new Date("April 1, 2014 00:01:00"));
 cdtd("#counter9",new Date("April 4, 2014 00:01:00"));
 cdtd("#counter10",new Date("April 5, 2014 00:01:00"));
  cdtd("#counter11",new Date("April 15, 2014 00:01:00"));
  cdtd("#counter12",new Date("April 17, 2014 00:01:00"));
```

Comment: getting alert message alert('We have lift off!'); when you refresh the page ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).load(function(){
        $('#divyouwanttohide').hide();
        return false;
    });
```

This should hide the div while the page is loading.  I think that is what you are asking here.   Youll have to show the div using an if statement or after this function.

Comment: but when i am using this code my div id not removing when time is less than zero...

Answer (score 0):

With Javascript only, one of the solutions is to use [cookies](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp) and not create the div element on reload. Another option would be to hide the div, but I think not creating it would be better.